# stuck with a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

am stuck with this linq query, all i need is to optimize the last price calculation, cause i get about a 1000 article, & a lot of sales so its getting slow ...

```
var result = from article in db.Entities.Articles 
select new{
     article.ID_ART,
     article.Designation,
     article.BuyPrice,
     article.SellPrice,
     LastPrice = (from sale in article.Sales where sale.Date == article.Sales.Max(X => X.Date) select sale.Price).FirstOrDefault()==0?
     article.BuyPrice: (from sale in article.Sales where sale.Date == article.Sales.Max(X => X.Date) select sale.Price).FirstOrDefault()
     }
```

Comment: If you trace the TSQL, is it doing this via a sub-query in the TSQL? Or is it pulling the `Sales` data back to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = from article in db.Entities.Articles 
    let lastPrice = (from sale in article.Sales 
                     orderby sale.Date descending 
                     select sale.Price).FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        article.ID_ART,
        article.Designation,
        article.BuyPrice,
        article.SellPrice,
        LastPrice = lastPrice ==0 ? article.BuyPrice : lastPrice
    }
```

Comment: never heard about "let" !, like magic, thank you its working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You should either `join` or `Include` Sales. I assume since it's a navigation property on article that it's an FK table.

Simply use `from article in db.Entities.Articles.Include("Sales")`... instead.

That will load sales for reference and prevent it from running a subquery when initializing the anonymous type.

Comment: It seems to me that bringing the `Sales` data back is entirely the opposite of what is desired here...